# JOIN functionality between multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

Tables:

Client

```
CID    Name
 1      A
 2      B
 3      C
 4      D
 5      E
 6..(And so on)
```

Visit

```
VID CID type
1   1   Med
2   3   Non
3   2   Non
4   6   Med
5   4   Med
6..(And so on)
```

Payment

```
PID   CID  amount
1      1       10
2      1       20
3      2       30
4      2       40
5      3       50
6..(And so on)
```

**Desired Output:**

```
CID  Name  type   amount
1     A     Med    10
1     A     Med    20
4     D     Med    NULL
(And so on..)
```

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
C.client_id
,C.name
,V.type
,P.payment

FROM Clients C
INNER JOIN Visit V
    ON C.cid=V.cid
LEFT JOIN Payment P
    ON V.cid=P.cid
```

I used a LEFT JOIN because I wanna see who made payments and who didn't.

**Question:** Do LEFT JOINS (or outer joins) pull in data based on the common id's in the CID of the left table resulting from preceding INNER JOINS(The common result set)? Or do they consider ALL the id's in the left table and ignore the INNER JOINS results altogether? 
I only want payment details of the clients existing in the inner joins and not outside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LEFT JOIN` will only run on rows that the `INNER JOIN` returns, or the `common data set` as you mention.

That is regardless of what the `LEFT JOIN` will return, the `INNER JOIN` is going to limit the result set based on `Visit V ON C.cid=V.cid`

This venn diagram shows the results that will be selected, the blue area is your data that will be returned. The order of the joins does not matter.

[image]

Comment: Is that also why the order in which they're used together matters? Meaning LEFT JOINS in the manner by which I am trying to obtain results should be after all the INNER JOINS?

Comment: matters in the sense of how they are defined by the "ON" clause, and from what to which table, but the order of appearance in the query is irrelevant, only the logical matching of records is.

Comment: @AmulyaSharma Answer updated, with hopefully helpful diagram.